# Can you join two lists with a user/person column and display in a DVWP?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, data-view-web-part, joined-view

I have two lists created in WSS 3.0:

1) User details - A custom list (person, supervisor etc) as I can't gain access to the User Information list and can't get XML Web Services to work.

2) Training details - A custom list of trainee, trainer and procedure.

I want to show the details of both lists in a dataview by joining via the trainee/person columns (these are people/group with presence columns limited to people and single entry).  I'm using SharePoint Designer 2007.  When I insert the "joined subview" data into the DVWP I get "No matching items found".

I have no XSL knowledge but believe the following code is probably what's being produced.

```
<xsl:variable name="Rows" select="../../../Courses_Attended/Rows/Row[@Attendee=$dvt_ParentRow/@Person]" />
```

I think the problem is that I need the User ID information from what's returned but don't know how to filter that out.

I can get this to work with text columns (i.e. enter the user information as a text field) but I wanted to keep the option of clicking on the user name for details.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to do something like:

```
<xsl:variable name="Rows" select="../../../Courses_Attended/Rows/Row[substring-before(substring-after(@Attendee, 'ID='), '&quot;')=$dvt_ParentRow/substring-before(substring-after(@Person, 'ID='), '&quot;')]" />
```